# Gulp file not compiling less file to css

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp file, and when I run it only the JavaScript files get complied and the less files doesn't get compiled, and I cannot seem to understand why is this happening.

This is my gulp file:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path'); 
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); 
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'); 
var less = require('gulp-less'); 
var watch = require('gulp-watch'); 
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint'); 
var jscs = require('gulp-jscs'); 
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var jsFiles = ['*.js', 'src/**/*.js'];

// js hints 
gulp.task('hints', function(){
    return gulp.src(jsFiles)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish', {
            verbose: true
        }))
        .pipe(jscs()); });

// less 
gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src('./public/src/less/main.less')
        .pipe(less({ paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/src/less/css')); });

// concat 
gulp.task('concat', ['concat:css', 'concat:js']); gulp.task('concat:css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'public/lib/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'public/lib/bower_components/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css',
            'public/lib/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
            'public/src/less/css/main.css'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/')); }); gulp.task('concat:js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'public/lib/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/jquery.localScroll/jquery.localScroll.min.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/jquery-waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js',
            'public/lib/bower_components/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js',
            'public/src/js/init.js',
            'public/src/js/utils.js',
            'public/src/js/main.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/')); });

// watch 
gulp.task('watch', ['watch:css', 'watch:js']); 
gulp.task('watch:css', function () {    
 gulp.watch('public/src/less/*.less', ['less', 'concat:css']); 
}); 
gulp.task('watch:js', function () {    
 gulp.watch('public/src/js/*.js', ['concat:js', 'hints']); 
});

gulp.task('build', [ 'less', 'concat']); 
gulp.task('development', [ 'less', 'concat', 'watch']);
```

When I run gulp development the css and js file gets created under the build folder but because the less files dont get compiled to css the css file under build folder has none of my styles.

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Is the less file containing styles? It won't output if the file is not containing rules. I've ran into this, and tried adding `html { height: 100%; }` to see if it worked, and it did.

Comment: @randy what do you mean if the file does not have rules? yes it does have styles.

Comment: @randy yes it does have styles in it

Comment: @beckas Try without `paths:`, so just `less()`.

Comment: @Leromul it doesnt work like that

Comment: But, isn't Gulp saying anything? Any error?